# Finding Max and Min Values of an Array returns 0

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm supposed to create an array and initialize it and afterwards I'm to write two helper methods: One for finding the max value of the array and one for the min value. But when I run it, both return 0. This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ArraysMethodsFiles
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int thisMinValue = minValue(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });
            int thisMaxValue = maxValue(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });
            int theseValues = values(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });
            Console.WriteLine(theseValues);
            Console.WriteLine(thisMinValue);
            Console.WriteLine(thisMaxValue);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static int values(int[] arr)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            arr = new int[10];
            for (int i = 0; i <= arr.Length; i++)
            {
                sum += i;
            }

            return sum;
        }

        static int maxValue(int[] arr) 
        {
            arr = new int[10];
            int max = arr.Max();
            return max;
        }

        static int minValue(int[] arr)
        {
            arr = new int[10];
            int min = arr.Min();
            return min;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read your code.  What do you think `arr = new int[10];` means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing the array passed to method with an empty array in each method.
Just remove this line from each method:

```
arr = new int[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an empty array inside each function, of size 10, then preforming the operation on that. Instead, rewrite your functions like this:

```
static int maxValue(int[] arr) => arr.Max();
static int minValue(int[] arr) => arr.Min();
```

But at that point, all you're function is doing is calling another, so you might as well drop those functions and just do this:

```
int thisMinValue = (new int[] { 1, 2, 3, /* ... */ 10 }).Min();
```

Comment: Oh, I see.. I just started learning programming so the "simple way of doing things" is something out of my reach right now.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the simple way isn't very simple. But keep it up, and happy coding (: